# InvokeProcess missing from the ToolBox?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

I want to use InvokeProcess to run a batch file.

Problem is that I can't find InvokeProcess in my ToolBox.

[image: No InvokeProcess]

How can I add this to my ToolBox?  I need to know what assembly it lives in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are missing all activities (not just InvokeProcess) from Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.
Those are to be found in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll

Furthermore it seems that in tab "Team Foundation Build Activities" you 're including what per default is the content of tab "Team Foundation LabManagement Activities" (which are members of Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Workflow.Activities).

In order to add this, just right-click on the tab and click the checkbox in "System.Activities Components":
[image]

Comment: Turns out I needed to add that DLL.  For those that read this, that dll can be found at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies

Comment: Thank you @Vaccano.... I lost quite a few minutes trying to find where the hell the dll was.

Comment: @julealgon where can i find the dll in vs2017

Comment: @Vaccano where can i find the dll in vs2017

Comment: @NithinChandran sorry I have no idea. Would have to search again.