# Could not load file or assembly 'LibGit2Sharp.GitServer, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xx' or one of its dependencies

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, workflow, build-definition

[image]I was trying to execute a powershell script after tfs build by customizing the default process template using vs2017. According to [this article](https://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/build-script-hooks-for-tfs-2012-builds) i have to use `InvokeProcess` and `ConvertWorkspaceItem` activities. Since it was not found in the tool box, referring [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170075/invokeprocess-missing-from-the-toolbox/7172716#comment89725033_7172716), I tried to add `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll` to the tool box. But the following error shows up

> Could not load file or assembly 'LibGit2Sharp.GitServer, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies

I am really stuck in this. Any help

Comment: What's the Powershell script did you run? Did the powershell script execute the tf commands and have you added tf.exe in environment variable yet?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Powershell script. The problem is that this assembly (`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll`) has a hard reference to `LibGit2Sharp.GitServer` but Microsoft forgot to add this assembly to the Team Explorer extension. The old version of this assembly on a TFS 2015 server does not reference `LibGit2Sharp.GitServer` but `LibGit2Sharp` and this assembly is available on the server **and** in the Team Explorer extension. So Microsoft should change this reference or simply ship the new assembly with the extension.

Comment: @Anateus seems like you are right. this problem doesn't exists on vs 2015

Comment: Did anyone find a way to load this file?